# make array in selected value picker react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i have trouble how to make array in selected picker in react native i want to make like this if value selected,

```
state = { selected: null, arr: [] }
<Picker
      selectedValue={selected}
      style={{ height: 20, width: 110 }}
      onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
        this.setState({ selected: itemValue })
        this.state.arr.push(selected)
      }}
    >
      {dummy.map((val, idx) => (
        <Picker.Item label={val.attendance} value={val.id} key={idx} />
      ))}
    </Picker>
```

i want to make if i choose value = ['present', 'present', 'sick', leave']

Comment: Could you include your entire component? It's also not recommended to mutate your state directly by pushing to it. You should use `setState` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<Picker
  selectedValue={selected}
  style={{ height: 20, width: 110 }}
  onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
    this.setState({
      selected: itemValue,
      arr: [...this.state.arr].push(selected)
    })
  }}
>
```